# Is creating an Islamic Q&A website considered a good deed and beneficial on the Day of Judgement?

Tags: internet, reward

I am going to develop an Islamic Q&A website for the Freebasic platform. Will that be beneficial for me on Judgement Day, and will that be counted as my Neki in Shariah?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it depends on the content. If it's correct, then the output will be positive. But, if it's the opposite then you will regret this step. My advice is:

- Think several times before posting anything, and be sure about it authenticity form several sources.
- Always cite references, to give the readers the opportunity to verify.
- Get your posts examined by a specialized person when it's necessary, in order to be "certain" about it.
- Every time it's possible, try to give different types of reasons to justify your answers. Because the reader might be a Muslim, a new Muslim, a non Muslim, ...

Comment: Good suggestions.